# Shortcut for Focusing Console Filter in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm frequently needing to filter out my Chrome console during web development. Unfortunately every time I want to filter for a different term, I must manually click the search box. I don't see anything about a shortcut for focusing the filter bar in the [Chrome devtools shortcut docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/), is there a way to assign a shortcut to do this? This would make using the filter much faster.

If there's an extension that will do it I'm also open to that.

[image]